# Character is out of Screen in 2D Unity Multiplayer Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

As you know positions are critical in multiplayer game and I want to define same position in different resolutions in my 2d multiplayer game.

My problem is like this: if my resolution is 1080p, it works nicely. However if resolution is set to 800x600, then the other character disappears because of the camera.

How can I make it right?

**1080p:**

[image: 1080p]

**800 x 600:**

[image: 800x600]

Comment: Can you zoom out enough so everyone seens what's critical (with some zoom limit)?

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution that might work in your case : [Controlling Aspect Ratio in Unity](http://gamedesigntheory.blogspot.com/2010/09/controlling-aspect-ratio-in-unity.html)

Answer (score 0):

change the z of the camera (Camera.main.transform.position =) by using the screen.width and screen.height and make the screen size inversely proportional to how zoomed in (close to 0 on the z-axis) the camera is